# Moving with cursor image left slide to right without jQuery in Widget code

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget, cursor

I want this widget code without jQuery. I checked all posts, but they do not help. its like SUmoME widget.

http://www.appsumo.com/clickminded-2016/

see the top right blue tab. i want that replace to pic in my blog.

I want from the left corner to right slider when mouse hover like this.pls see demo.

Sorry for my bad english :(

**HTML**

```
    <div id="css">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/531885101043302400/4fDwYFQb.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    img {
  position: relative;
  margin: -500px;
  left: 0;
  transition: left .5s;
}


#css:hover img {
  left: 400px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nP7Lc/285/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here i found it easy steps .... just copy this to HTML widget ...works perfect**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<!-- 
$(document).ready(function() {$(".gplusbox").hover(function() {$(this).stop().animate({right: "-80"}, "medium");}, function() {$(this).stop().animate({right: "-330"}, "medium");}, 100);}); 
//--> 
</script> 
<style type="text/css">
.gplusbox{
background: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-iOMr0KnDFkY/V17Zm0bj49I/AAAAAAAABGw/Ag_ig7sBwYE5qXn6evvNTFSg9KvhQT7lACLcB/h250/Untitled-1.jpg") no-repeat scroll left center transparent !important;
display: block;
float: right;
height: 320px;
padding: 0 0px 0 40.5px;
width: 325px;
z-index: 99999;
position:fixed;
right:-330px;
top:20%;
}

</style>
<div class="gplusbox"><div>
<a href="hhttps://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/531885101043302400/4fDwYFQb.png"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/531885101043302400/4fDwYFQb.png" /></a>

</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care for browsers supporting html5 and css3, use [css animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation). The syntax's a bit like your existing code when it comes to the *key frames*.
If you wanna support all browsers, use jQuery's `animate` funcion, which changes the styles every 100ms or so, thus doesn't require css3 support. The css3 animation solution has a better performance but everyone can afford to run jQuery's animation, you won't really feel any difference.

Answer (score 0):

i hope understand your question correctly...
i made it for you :)

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.parent{
top:100px;
padding:3px;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  cursor:pointer;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.parent span{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
transition: left .5s;
left: 0;
margin-left:-100px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}

.parent:hover span{
left:100px;
}
```

```html
<a class="parent"> >
    <span>
       <img src="http://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/facebook.png" alt=""><br>
       <img src="http://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/twitter.png" alt="" />
    </span>    
</a>
```

hope its good!

Comment: what do you mean ?does it match your question ?

Comment: matched but all pics are resized and icons bigger and all mixed ... this slide showing main page but i want only in each post

Comment: you can set your own size on the css properties...what do you want to do? can you upload an image?

Comment: i dont know what is the problem because i dont have all your code :/ did you notice that i have img tag in my css...? do you have more img tags in your code?

Comment: i changed some code .. slide is working but not moving vertically !! is there a change to?

Comment: no but you can give it an id too, just for sure. give the img tag also an id.

Answer (score 0):

if you have `span` tag on your code it will effect this tag too... i suggest you to give this specific `span` an `id` and probably it will work.
here is an example:

```css
.parent #mySpan{
position:absolute;
top:150px;
transition: left .5s;
left: 0;
margin-left:-50px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}

.parent:hover #mySpan{
left:50px;
}
```

```html
<a class="parent"> 
    <span id='mySpan'>
       <img src="http://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/facebook.png" alt=""><br>
    </span>    
</a>
```

Comment: yup i already did !!
slide is working but not moving vertically !! is there a change to?

Comment: no but you can give it an id too, just for sure. give the img tag also an id.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Javasript code without (HTML,CSS) working in widget.. but how to do like this mouse hover? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nP7Lc/285/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--
var imgObj = null;
var animate ;
function init(){
   imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
   imgObj.style.position= 'absolute'; 
   imgObj.style.top = '240px';
   imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
   imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';
   moveRight();
} 
function moveRight(){
if (parseInt(imgObj.style.left)<=10)
{
   imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
   imgObj.style.visibility='visible';
   animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
   //stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,20);
  }
else
  stop();
  f();
}

function stop(){
   clearTimeout(animate);
}
window.onload =init;
//-->
</script>
<img id="myImage" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LxuD_Ceq6NrRGBW2mF_6Cy9zeO_vqkV8ZTRMdzjc_LxE0InnXBLp1_BkWuyhlg0EMJPt-Njzzp5_4cuR562m6dh8QNTW_1kzsf9pXcXiKI2ZK6wEMJH2TAAiQqpQUewNMKI=s0-d" style="margin-left:170px;" />
```